# Google Data Studio Table: Dividing Data that has 2 different Years

Tags: looker-studio

I need to produce a table that has Quotes win%. The formula is #won divide by #sent.
My problem is, there are quotes that are won within a year but were sent in different years.

(My data comes from BigQuery)

The data looks like this:

```
Sale    Sent    Won
sale1   2019    2020
sale2   2019    2020
sale3   2016    2017
sale4   2017    2019
sale5   2020    2020
sale6   2020    2020
sale7   2018    2018
sale8   2016    2016
sale9   2015    2016
sale10  2016    2017
sale11  2016    2018
sale12  2018    2019
```

I'd like to be able to create a table in data studio like this:

```
Year   SENT    WON  WIN%
2016     4     2    50%
2017     1     2    200%
2018     2     2    100%
2019     2     2    100%
2020     2     4    200%
```

I would love to see if this is possible in google data studio. Any suggestion is highly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Added a [Google Data Studio Report](https://datastudio.google.com/reporting/24d612fe-e2b7-42e7-96ad-cf8b1aadbe54) to demonstrate, as well as a GIF showing the process below.

One approach is to restructure the Data at the *Data Set* and use [Calculated Fields](https://support.google.com/datastudio/answer/6299685) in a [Table](https://support.google.com/datastudio/answer/7189044):

**1) Data Transformation**
The data needs to be transformed from the current [*Wide* structure to a *Long* data structure](https://support.google.com/datastudio/answer/6295223). One way it can be achieved in Google Sheets is by using the formula below (`Sheet1` represents the input sheet; consult embedded Google Sheet for clarification):

```
=ArrayFormula(QUERY({
{Sheet1!A:A,IF(LEN(Sheet1!A:A),"Sent",""),Sheet1!B:B};
{Sheet1!A:A,IF(LEN(Sheet1!A:A),"Won",""),Sheet1!C:C}
},"Select * Where Col3 is not null Label Col2 'Dimension', Col3 'Year'",1))
```

**2) Table**
- ***Dimension***: `Year`
- ***Sort***: `Year` in Ascending order
- ***Metrics***: Add the 3 calculated fields below:

**3) Calculated Fields**
The formulas below create the metrics used in the Table above (Formula `3.1` and `3.2` need to be added at the *Data Source-level*, while `3.3` can be added at the *Chart-level* if required):

> ***3.1) SENT***
>
> ```
> COUNT(CASE
>    WHEN REGEXP_MATCH(Dimension, "Sent") THEN Year
>    ELSE NULL END)
> ```
>
> ***3.2) WON***
>
> ```
> COUNT(CASE
>    WHEN REGEXP_MATCH(Dimension, "Won") THEN Year
>    ELSE NULL END)
> ```
>
> ***3.3) WIN%***
>
> ```
> WON / SENT
> ```

[image: 5]]

Comment: Hi Nimantha, I apologize. I should have mentioned that my datasource is BigQuery. I'll edit the post to have that reflected.

Comment: Also, Is it possible to create a calculated field that will act as a "Year" Dimension so both Sent and Won can be shown in one table?